# same table as two and same column

Tags: mysql

I have two table:
1-messages_system_data

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages_system_data` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `msgId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `theSubject` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `sentMemId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `receiveMemId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

2-members

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `theName` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

I need to retrieve sender message name and receiver massage name. messages_system_data keep id of sender and receiver id. I should only use one sql command. I write like this:

```
SELECT messages_system_data.theSubject, ?(here should be receiver ),?( sender name)  FROM  messages_system_data,members WHERE messages_system_data.sentMemId=members.id AND messages_system_data.receiveMemId=members.id LIMIT :limit, :offset
```

in this sql two members tables join and how can i reach this members tables of theName column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem appears to be that you are not comfortable joining to a given table twice in the same query. In my opinion it is easier to be precise about this sort of thing (and about joins in general) if you use explicit join syntax rather than comma syntax.

```
SELECT
    messages_system_data.theSubject,
    sender.theName AS sender_name,
    recipient.theName AS recipient_name
FROM
    messages_system_data
    JOIN members AS sender ON messages_system_data.sentMemId = sender.id
    JOIN members AS recipient ON messages_system_data.receiveMemId = recipient.id
```

Incidentally, why is it that `members.id` is a `BIGINT` but `messages_system_data.sentMemId` and `messages_system_data.receiveMemId` are `INT`s? They should be the same type.

Comment: thanks mate your sql works perfectly.I work on Company which did that.I dont know why type is different